# UseBasicParsing doesnt return HTML form

Tags: powershell

I am working on creating a form login monitor for a webpage. Here is the code:

```
$loginbase = '<input omitted>'
$loginURL = $loginbase + '<input omitted>'
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($loginURL + 'logonform.jsp')
return $r;

$form = $r.Forms[0];

return $form

$form.Fields['aps'] = '<input omitted>';
$form.Fields['usr'] = '<input omitted>';
$form.Fields['pwd'] = '<input omitted>';

$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($loginURL + $form.Action) -Method POST -Body $form.Fields;

if ($r.Content -match 'setup()') {

    if ($r.StatusCode -eq 200) {

        Write-Host 'Message:' $r.StatusDescription;
        Write-Host 'Statistic:' $r.StatusCode;
        Exit 0;
    }

    Write-Host 'Message:' $r.StatusDescription;
    Write-Host 'Statistic:' $r.StatusCode;
    Exit 1;
}

Write-Host 'Message: Did not login';
Write-Host 'Statistic: 1';
Exit 1;
```

This works just fine outside of the monitoring platform, but when I put this script into the platform I get the following error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter and try again. 
At line:3 char:6 
+ $r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($loginURL + 'logonform.jsp') 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : NotImplemented: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], NotSupportedException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletIEDomNotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand 

Cannot index into a null array. 
At line:5 char:1 
+ $form = $r.Forms[0]; 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray 

Cannot index into a null array. 
At line:7 char:1 
+ $form.Fields['aps'] = '<input omitted>'; 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray 

Cannot index into a null array. 
At line:8 char:1 
+ $form.Fields['usr'] = '<input omitted>'; 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray 

Cannot index into a null array. 
At line:9 char:1 
+ $form.Fields['pwd'] = '<input omitted>'; 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray 

Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. 
At line:11 char:6 
+ $r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($loginURL + $form.Action) -Method POST -Body $form. ... 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Following the suggestion of the first error, I added '-UseBasicParsing' to my initial Invoke-WebRequest statement. When I run the script either inside or outside of the monitoring platform what occurs is that none of the forms or inputfields are pulled from the HTML. I get the following:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!--
                    ©2010 - 2013 SAP AG or an SAP affiliate company.  All rights reserved.

                    SAP and other SAP products and services mentioned herein as well as their respective logos are trademarks or registered...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Content-Length: 2561
                    Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
                    Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2016 15:31:12 GMT
                    Expires: 0
                    Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DE3280200E764687D90E63E50A65452F; Path=/AdminTools...
Forms             : 
Headers           : {[Content-Length, 2561], [Content-Type, text/html;charset=utf-8], [Date, Tue, 11 Oct 2016 15:31:12 GMT], [Expires, 0]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : 
RawContentLength  : 2561
```

Ive tried to find an alternate solution on both google and the support forums of our monitoring platform, but neither have turned much up outside of the standard tutorials of how to use Invoke-WebRequest.

Comment: If you can use an external library then use [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm a big fan of HTMLAgilityPack but using it (or any other way of parsing) would require additional code to get the string or object types needed to pass back to `iwr` to log in to the form; it would be far from a drop-in replacement for how easy `iwr` makes this natively. Props if you'd like to add that answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you're trying to use, which is HTML parsed into an object model, requires Internet Explorer to be available and initialized. `-UseBasicParsing` specifically doesn't do that parsing, for the situation where you don't need it, and where IE is not available (like on Server Core).

If you are not running server core, and IE is actually available, then the problem is likely this:

> Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete.

In that case, just run IE for the first time and that should fix it.

If the script is being run as a service account, then make sure that you log in once with that account and initialize IE (it's per-user).

Comment: Hmm, I didnt think of that so I made sure that IE's first-launch config was complete (it wasnt) for the service account. I am still getting the error, but I am going to go back to the support forums for the product and see what they have to say.

Comment: @Resin I also found [this page](http://wahlnetwork.com/2015/11/17/solving-the-first-launch-configuration-error-with-powershells-invoke-webrequest-cmdlet/) which uses Group Policy to disable first-run. That might work better. I also vaguely recall a bug where in some instances the error remained after first-run config, but I can't find any references to that right now. I also add that you should completely close and re-open powershell after doing the IE first run before trying `iwr` again.

Comment: So I wanted to come back and let everyone know what the solution was in case some poor soul ends up reading this thread for a solution.

The monitoring solution runs its services as the Local System. So I had to make a registry edit to IE to 'Prevent running first run wizard' under Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer.

I had to set this to enabled and then select one of the options (I chose the second option).

Comment: Which is exactly what you posted

Comment: @Resin I think disabling first run wizard was the right thing to do (whether by registry or group policy), but with `psexec.exe` (from SysInternals, not PowerShell related), you might have been able to run IE as `SYSTEM` (perish the though) to accomplish first-run.

Comment: @Resin 's comment above is the location for GPO. On WinServer 2016, the registry key is "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\". Create the following keys "Internet Explorer\Main" then a DWORD (32-bit) called "DisableFirstRunCustomize" with a value of 1

Comment: PowerShell is about automation so the idea of having to manually start IE to achieve sounds horrible and defeats the purpose of using a scripting language to automate things. How can we add a line or two to code that willl *silently* start IE in the background to complete this First Run Customisation? Or, is the solution to use the "DisableFirstRunCustomize" item and then somehow start IE as a background process? Can someone show how they achieved the goal of initializing IE silently? I can do what @DonBecker says, but then what is the best way to start IE silently?

Comment: @YorSubs yeah it's certainly not ideal. What might be interesting to note is that starting in PowerShell 6 `Invoke-WebRequest` _only_ does basic parsing, so I think not relying on the feature is a good idea. It's worth checking the "basic" parsing to see if it already gives you what you need. If not, I'm a fan of using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) for parsing HTML. You're going to get the same type of objects back but in the end it's much more powerful.

Comment: @briantist, great, I have to look into that pack but it is an additional install. I have to play with `-UseBasicParsing` more though a complete solution would be great. As a starter, here is the line to add the part @DonBacker mentions. `New-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" -Name "DisableFirstRunCustomize" -Value 1 -Force`. Now what do we do to start IE silently? I've tried: `$IE = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application" ; $IE.Navigate("https://www.google.com/")` but not getting good results. i.e. `iwr` that I use after still fails :( ...